# how to paste in next empty cell to the right?

Tags: excel, vba, rows, offset, paste

I'm trying to copy values from matching cell values with offset and past value in the next empty cell to right. I'm getting error "Type mismatch"

```
Dim ThisCell1 As Range
Dim ThisCell2 As Range
Dim LCol As Long
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For Each ThisCell1 In Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A1089")
        For Each ThisCell2 In Sheets("sheet0").Range("b2:b3392")
            If ThisCell2.Value = ThisCell1.Value Then

                ThisCell2.Offset(0, 1).Copy

                ThisCell1.End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Exit For
                End If
            Next ThisCell2
            Next ThisCell1
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: `ThisCell2.Value = ThisCell1.Value`: You can't compare a single cell to an entire range.

Comment: You are trying to compare the value of one cell to an entire range. What is it you're trying to accomplice, do you want to know if the value in column B is anywhere in column A, or do you want to know if the value is identical to the one on the same row in column A?

Comment: i need to compare column a and column b

Comment: so i added  " For Each ThisCell1 In Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A1089")"

Comment: this seams to work but copy all info to sheet("sheet1").column b.  i need it to copy to next empty cell to right

Comment: Please post your updated code.

Comment: edit code above

Answer (score 0):

This sub does what you require, and will be a massive lot quicker than using the double loop you use. It uses the formula `Match` as an argument, which will find on which row a match is found. It will then go to that row and find the last used column and copy over the offset of the original string:

```
Dim ThisCell1 As Range
Dim ThisCell2 As Range
Dim LCol As Long
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each ThisCell2 In Sheets("sheet0").Range("b2:b3392")
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(ThisCell2.Value, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1089"))) Then
                    Sheets("Sheet1"). Cells(Application.Match(ThisCell2.Value, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1089")), Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Value = ThisCell2.Offset(, 1)
                Exit For 'This insures you only ever get one match. Is that what is needed?
                End If
            Next ThisCell2
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I'm not sure if this is the exact logic you were looking for, if not let me know. This is the closest approximation I could find to your original code comparing your value to a range.

Comment: Ok that code runs but nothing paste on sheet1 column B.  Sheet0 has a line list in column B with duplicates. and sheet0 column C has number with no duplicates. Sheet 1 column A has the same line list as sheet0 column A but without duplicates. i need to compare both line list for match. and get offset value.copy to sheet1 column b if column is blank, if not blank then use next column.

Comment: Sorry this was my working example, referring to different sheets. I've adapted the sheets to your original code.